# How to Update text in Tkinter Label/Canvas widget using for loop?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am having issues in updating text in label as well as in canvas.
Updating text in canvas itself was tiresome. Didn't find anything useful.

My project is here - https://github.com/MRDGH2821/Words-Per-Minute-/tree/beta

What I wish to do -
Display a paragraph, word by word (with some delay in between)

What I thought while writing the code -
Paragraph will be in file. The code will read the paragraph, extract 1st word & put them into label widget. After a delay, 1st word will disappear & 2nd word will be put to display. And so on.

What the code actually does -
Instead of showing the whole word, its showing 1st letter of 1st word. I used for loop to update the text displayed in label widget, but it doesn't update/refresh.

Here is the code snippet -

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.bind("<F11>", lambda event: root.attributes("-fullscreen", not root.attributes("-fullscreen")))
root.bind("<Escape>", lambda event: root.attributes("-fullscreen", False))
root.bind("<F1>", lambda event: os.exit(0))

w = tk.StringVar()

labelFlash = tk.Label(root, bg='Black', width=root.winfo_screenwidth(), height=root.winfo_screenheight(),
                      anchor="center", text="Sample", fg="White", font="Times " + str(cofg.GetFontSize()), textvariable=w)
labelFlash.pack()
for word in words:
    w.set(word)
    labelFlash.config(text=word)
```

Comment: What does _"Updating text in canvas itself was tiresome."_ mean? It's one line of code to update text on a canvas. Have you verified that immediately before the loop, `words` is a list of words rather than a string of characters?

Comment: @BryanOakley, I was actually using Canvas method to carry out the text displaying stuff.

This ```words``` is a list of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.bind("<F11>", lambda event: root.attributes("-fullscreen", not root.attributes("-fullscreen")))
root.bind("<Escape>", lambda event: root.attributes("-fullscreen", False))
root.bind("<F1>", lambda event: os.exit(0))

w = tk.StringVar()

labelFlash = tk.Label(root, bg='Black', width=root.winfo_screenwidth(), height=root.winfo_screenheight(),
                      anchor="center", text="Sample", fg="White", font="Times " , textvariable=w)
labelFlash.pack()
MSG="Hello World"
str_list=[]
for i in range(len(MSG)):
    str_list.append(MSG[:i+1])
words=str_list


indx=0
def update():
    global indx
    if indx>=len(words):
        indx=0
    w.set(words[indx])
    labelFlash.config(text=words[indx])
    indx+=1
    root.after(500, update)#500 ms


update()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you described what you did. Otherwise, we have to compare this code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character to see what has changed.